# How can I map cost and assets in gcp

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-billing

I have used BigQuery and DataSet to store billing data.

I am not able to map line items from billing data to asset data line item. For example I am getting asset id in asset data, but not getting asset id in billing data.

So here I am facing issues to understand which cost, line item is for which asset? Can anyone help me on this?

Note : I am considering mainly these types of assets:

1. Google Compute Engine
2. Google App Engine
3. Storage
4. SQL
5. Loadbalancer

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean with Asset.id? 

I've checked my own Bigquery export and the fields like Service_id or service_description could match this value you mean.

I can post them as an answer (Service.id and service.description) if you need them

Comment: Asset Id means resource id such as compute instance will have one id field that is asset id here. I have one compute instance running and i want to identify that instance in billing invoice line item. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Asset Id in the billing data structure. Although, you could set [labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) in the instances to then use the export to filter by them.

Since labels are key/value pairs, you could use the same key and different values to differentiate each resource's cost.

You could see a few samples in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples?hl=en). i.e :

```
SELECT
  labels.value as environment,
  SUM(cost) as cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(labels) as labels
  ON labels.key = "environment"
GROUP BY environment;
```

Also, for the load balancer, you could look into the instance template to customize labels here as well.

Comment: Yes labels are there but the problem here with label is, labels are not mandatory fields so if labels are there then well and good. But I am facing issues in case of there is no labels available on resource, then I am unable to identify resources on billing invoice line items.

Comment: Indeed there is a limitation on what resources labels are applied to. Nonetheless, you could play with  `service.id`, `service.description` and `sku.description`. These will return more information on resources such as CLoud SQL, Cloud Storage, App Engine, etc., which you can filter in Bigquery. Also you may want to take a look at this [Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) documentation which may help you understand charges a bit better.